# Ajuda com o Heroku, não mostra páginas com a linguagem Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Olá, preciso da ajuda dos nobres detentores do conhecimento. Estou estudando Ruby on Rails pelo site da Codecademy. Peguei umas coisas que aprendi lá, e tentei colocar online no Heroku. Deu tudo certo no início, tudo perfeito. Mas de repente, ao tentar entrar em uma página específica, ela mostrava o seguinte erro:
[image: Erro mostrado ao tentar acessar a página NO SERVIDOR.]

Tal erro não é mostrado no localhost. Então resolvi começar do zero e fazendo deploy a cada passo pra achar o problema. O problema foi que, uma página normal com html puro, abre tranquilamente, mas uma com Ruby (dentro do arquivo) dá esse problema.

### O seguinte código está gerando o problema (acredito eu)

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <div class="message">
        <p class="content"><%= message.content %></p>
        <p class="time"><%= message.created_at %></p>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

### O link para caso queiram conferir pessoalmente é esse:

#### https://segundoteste.herokuapp.com/

Tem 2 botões, o botão "Mensagens!" tem o trecho acima no código e mostra o erro. E o botão Teste não tem e não mostra erro.

Alguém gostaria de gastar algum pouco tempo pra me ajudar? Será de grande ajuda. Obrigado.

Atualização:
[image: Controller]

Essa é o controller da página com problema.
Arquivo dentro de db/migrate:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Log:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seja bem vindo, comece fazendo o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), bom você configurou a **rota** em `routes.rb` ?

Comment: Configurei. Segue código:
Rails.application.routes.draw do <br>
  root 'pages#home' <br>
  get '/messages' => 'messages#index' <br>
  get '/testando' => 'testando#teste' <br>
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see  <br>http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html <br>
end <br>
No localhost funciona normalmente

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/261831/edit) sua pergunta e coloque mais informações, como está essa variável `messages` ...  Veja no `Heroku` o log da aplicação.

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, mas como vejo o log? é o que ele mostra após o deploy?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pessoal que ver agora, consegui resolver o problema

O problema era o banco de dados. Não existia a tabela do código no banco de dados do Heroku, por que eu não tinha migrado ela! Que burrice minha. Por isso que funcionava no localhost. 
O que eu fiz foi o segunte:
-- Olhei os Logs, um obrigado ao **wmsouza** (não sei marcar, vai assim mesmo) por me lembrar que eles existem.
-- Nos logs falava que não tinha conseguido se conectar com a tabela "messages" no banco de dados. Óbvio né. *EU NÃO TINHA MIGRADO ELA PRO BANCO DE DADOS DA HEROKU, ELA ESTAVA SÓ NO MEU PC* por isso que não dava certo.

-- Eu achei depois de tanto procurar, a página https://data.heroku.com/datastores que tem os dados necessários pra fazer a conexão.
-- Peguei esses dados e os coloquei no arquivo **database.yml**.
-- Também conectei meu pgAdmin3 com esses dados. 
-- Dei um **rake db:migrate** e um **rake db:seed**. E pronto, resolveu o problema, a página abre normalmente agora, e mostra as mensagens que estão no servidor.

Só isso.

Vlw a atenção galera, estou motivado novamente a aprender Ruby on Rails